# Getting readable information from Amazon sdk ruby

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Maybe someone could help me with an issue while working with Amazon SDK for Ruby.

When trying to retrieve information with commands like `"get_bucket_login"` or `"get_bucket_location"` what I get as a response is:

```
<Seahorse::Client::Response:....>
```

According to the documentation, these requests should return strings.
    What am I missing? Someone found the same issue?

Comment: Please format your question corretcly, and put in the error message(s) you receive

Comment: I have fixed the question layout to improve readability.

Comment: Sorry for that, it was my first message!

Answer (score 1):

Seahorse is part of the core of the SDK:
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/tree/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/seahorse

The clients of all the services are modeled to use the Base of this.

Now back to your question:
You get an "empty" response as in it does not conform to what the client base is used to.

=== for **get_bucket_location** ===

the way to get your bucket location is the following:

```
resp = s3.get_bucket_location(bucket: "mybucketname")
puts resp.data.location_constraint
```

empty string means US Standard, per documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html

the code that monkey patches this in is here: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/53712d3e4583c982837fb3a301fa2c67226a05ff/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/s3_get_bucket_location_fix.rb

== for **get_bucket_login** ==

I don't see this method on the client. If it's logging instead of login, you can see the response structure in the documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Client.html#get_bucket_logging-instance_method